# JOIN 4 tables in one (Oracle R11)

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, erp

I need to create a query that shows the "Legal Entity", "Application Name", "Close Date" and "Period" I'm working with Oracle R11, Right now I've found the query for

"Legal Entity"

```
SELECT name
FROM hr_organization_information HOI
INNER JOIN hr_all_organization_units HAOU
ON HOI.ORGANIZATION_ID = Haou.Organization_Id
WHERE HOI.org_information_context LIKE 'Legal Entity Accounting'
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

and for "Application Name, Close Date, Period"

```
SELECT A.APPLICATION_ID,
       B.APPLICATION_NAME,
       TO_CHAR(A.END_DATE,'HH24:MI DD-MON-YYYYI'),
       A.PERIOD_NUM
FROM GL_PERIOD_STATUSES A
INNER JOIN FND_APPLICATION_TL B ON A.APPLICATION_ID = B.APPLICATION_ID
WHERE A.Application_Id=101
  AND LANGUAGE='US'
  OR A.APPLICATION_ID=200
  AND LANGUAGE='US'
  OR A.APPLICATION_ID=222
  AND LANGUAGE='US';
```

Separately but I haven't found the way to join them in one query, can you help me with that?

Comment: You need to determine if these tables Relate in a PK/FK way or through other tables relate.    you can always "Cross join" the results so each legal entity name is associated with all the records from the 2nd query; but I doubt that's what you're after.  As no tables from one query match another; we can't figure out how to get them to relate.  Maybe HR organizations tie to FND Applications somehow? or it ties to GL Periods?  without these details really can't help.  Does `organization_ID` and  `Application_ID` exist in the same table together somewhere?

Comment: I'd use this to check if both columns exist in same table `SELECT Table_name
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME in ('ORGANIZATION_ID', 'APPLICATION_ID')
GROUP BY Table_name
HAVING count(Distinct COLUMN_NAME) > 1` then i'd evaluate the results to determine which of those results if any; best suit the need.  If none of those work then you have no direct relation and you have to look at the ERD or dependencies to see if you can find a way to see how they relate.  or Ask the system architect/ reference existing source code  (ALL_SOURCE) to see if you can find a way of doing it.

Comment: Just guessing, but like xQbert, I would suspect that an application (in the FND_APPLICATION_TL table) is submitted by an organization unit (from the HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS). Either that, or an application is submitted by an individual who works in a unit - in that case you need to relate everything through a FIFTH table, perhaps EMPLOYEES. Now, as an aside: the WHERE clause in the second query can be simplified to `where a.application_id in (101, 200, 222) and language = 'US')` (and you should probably qualify `language` with its table alias).

Comment: To help you further, it would be good to know some column names in your relevant tables. Especially if you can tell (by the column name) if an application is submitted by a unit or by something/someone else. Start with the primary key column in that table, if there is one.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, yours advices were so useful and I've found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antonio, I think Brian has given you sound advice.  Posting to an EBS forum (or whatever application this is) might also be worthwhile if his advice has not lead you to the answer.  I will offer that sometimes the way to join table_A and table_B is through table_C.  That is, if you do not find any directly related data in the queries of one se to one of the tables in the other set then look at the FK defined on and pointing to these tables to see if you can find a table not currently part of either query that relates the sets.  You figure out how to join each of your current queries to it and that is how you join the two queries together.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

The advices that all of you gave to me were useful, I've found the table HR_LEGAL_ENTITIES (Table C) that have two columns that allow me to join Table A with Table B, the final query was:

```
SELECT  HAOU.NAME, 
        FAT.APPLICATION_NAME, 
        TO_CHAR(GPS.END_DATE,'HH24:MI DD-MON-YYYY'), 
        GPS.PERIOD_NUM
FROM    HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS HAOU 
INNER JOIN HR_LEGAL_ENTITIES HLE
ON  HLE.ORGANIZATION_ID = HAOU.ORGANIZATION_ID
INNER JOIN GL_PERIOD_STATUSES GPS
ON HLE.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID = GPS.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID
INNER JOIN  FND_APPLICATION_TL FAT
ON GPS.APPLICATION_ID = FAT.APPLICATION_ID
WHERE GPS.Application_Id IN (101,200,222) AND LANGUAGE='US'
ORDER BY NAME ASC;

Regards!
```